# Run a different installer with my ClickOnce installer

Tags: .net, winforms, clickonce

I was searching about how to do this but no avail.

I have a Winforms application and published it by mean of ClickOnce. It works, however, that application uses a device which needs a driver to be installed.

Currently, to use the application, after ClickOnce application installation user should run a "setup.exe" corresponding to the driver installation.

Is there a way to include that "setup.exe" as part of the ClickOnce installer? it can be run in first or last place. Order of installation is not relevant.

Thanks.

Comment: Have you seen ["Install prerequisites with a ClickOnce application"](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/deployment/how-to-install-prerequisites-with-a-clickonce-application)?

Comment: You first need to [create a bootstrapper package](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/deployment/creating-bootstrapper-packages?view=vs-2022&WT.mc_id=DT-MVP-5003235) ([Example](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/deployment/walkthrough-creating-a-custom-bootstrapper-to-show-a-privacy-prompt?view=vs-2022&WT.mc_id=DT-MVP-5003235)), then [include and install prerequisite](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/deployment/how-to-install-prerequisites-with-a-clickonce-application?view=vs-2022&WT.mc_id=DT-MVP-5003235).

Answer (score 1):

You need to [create a bootstrapper package](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/deployment/creating-bootstrapper-packages?view=vs-2022&WT.mc_id=DT-MVP-5003235) for your external setup.exe and install it as a [prerequisite](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/deployment/how-to-install-prerequisites-with-a-clickonce-application?view=vs-2022&WT.mc_id=DT-MVP-5003235) for the ClickOnce installer.

I've shared step by step example to show how you can do that. You can also find a few useful links to learn more at the bottom of the post.

**Example - Create a custom bootstrapper package for custom setup.exe to install as a prerequisite using ClickOnce**

Here is a step by step example which shows you how you can create a custom bootstrapper package and add it as a prerequisite to your ClickOnce setup. In the following example I assume you have a setup.exe and ExternalSetup.msi and name of your external dependency is ExternalSetup. Follow these steps:

1. Go to the following folder:

   ```
   C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft SDKs\ClickOnce Bootstrapper\Packages
   ```
2. Create the following file/folder structure:

   ```
   ExternalSetup             [Folder]
      en                     [Folder]
         eula.rtf            [File]
         package.xml         [File]
      ExternalSetup.msi      [File]
      setup.exe              [File]
      product.xml            [File]
   ```

   *Note:*

   - Per each culture of the custom installer you need a folder for enula and package.
   - eula.rtf is the end user license agreement of the external setup.
   - product.xml file describe the contents of the bootstrapper
   - package.xml file describe the localization-specific aspects of your package
   - If you don't have a .msi file, just ignore it.
3. Here is the content for `product.xml`:

   ```
   <Product
     xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/developer/2004/01/bootstrapper"
     ProductCode="Microsoft.Sample.EULA">
    <!-- Defines the list of files to be copied on build. -->
    <PackageFiles CopyAllPackageFiles="true">
        <PackageFile Name="setup.exe"/>
        <PackageFile Name="ExternalSetup.msi"/>
    </PackageFiles>

    <!-- Defines how to run the Setup package.-->
    <Commands >
        <Command PackageFile = "setup.exe" Arguments=''>
            <ExitCodes>
                <ExitCode Value="0" Result="Success" />
                <ExitCode Value="-1" Result="Fail" String="Failed" />
                <DefaultExitCode Result="Fail" FormatMessageFromSystem="true" String="GeneralFailure" />
            </ExitCodes>
        </Command>
    </Commands>
   </Product>
   ```
4. Here is the content of `package.xml`:

   ```
   <Package
     xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/developer/2004/01/bootstrapper"
     Name="DisplayName"
     Culture="Culture"
     LicenseAgreement="eula.rtf">
    <PackageFiles>
        <PackageFile Name="eula.rtf"/>
    </PackageFiles>

    <!-- Defines a localizable string table for error messages. -->
    <Strings>
        <String Name="DisplayName">External Setup</String>
        <String Name="Culture">en</String>
        <String Name="Failed">Failed with -1.</String>
        <String Name="GeneralFailure">General failure.</String>
    </Strings>
   </Package>
   ```
5. Add some test content for your `eula.rtf`.
6. If VS is open, make sure you close close and reopen it.
7. In your Windows Form Project which you want to distribute using ClickOnce, right-click and choose *Properties*, then go to *Publish* tab and click on *Prerequisites...* button, choose *External Setup* and select *Download prerequisites from the same location and my application*.

   [image]
8. Build and Publish the application.
9. Install the application from the publish.

**More information**

- [Create bootstrapper packages](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/deployment/creating-bootstrapper-packages?view=vs-2022&WT.mc_id=DT-MVP-5003235)
- [How to: create a product manifest](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/deployment/how-to-create-a-product-manifest?view=vs-2022&WT.mc_id=DT-MVP-5003235)
- [How to: create a package manifest](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/deployment/how-to-create-a-package-manifest?view=vs-2022&WT.mc_id=DT-MVP-5003235)
- [How to: Create a localized bootstrapper package](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/deployment/how-to-create-a-localized-bootstrapper-package?view=vs-2022&WT.mc_id=DT-MVP-5003235)
- [Walkthrough: Create a custom bootstrapper with a privacy prompt](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/deployment/walkthrough-creating-a-custom-bootstrapper-to-show-a-privacy-prompt?view=vs-2022&WT.mc_id=DT-MVP-5003235)
- [Product and package schema reference](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/deployment/product-and-package-schema-reference?view=vs-2022&WT.mc_id=DT-MVP-5003235)